# Не могу понять, для чего нужно использовать свойство box-sizing в CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем здравствуйте!
У меня такой вопрос, продолжил я изучение HTML/CSS, и я не могу понять, для чего вообще нужно применять свойство box-sizing для HTML-элементов в CSS. Если кто сможет объяснить более понятно, то было-бы не плохо!

Answer (score 8):

Размер элемента складывается из высоты/ширины его содержимого + размеры `padding`'ов + размеры `border`.

Если Вы задаёте элементу `width` и `height`, по-умолчанию, это будет шириной/высотой именно содержимого.

То есть, если Вы добавляете свойства `padding`/`border`, то визуально элемент увеличится.

`Box-sizing` меняет это поведение. Если Вы укажете ему значение `border-box`, то размеры `padding` и `border` будут включены в `width`/`height` данного элемента.

Подробнее: [webref.ru](https://webref.ru/css/box-sizing)

Answer (score -1):

Не можешь понять - не используй. Когда элементы начнут вылазить на величину отступов (или, возможно, переноситься на следующую строку), поймёшь и применишь `box-sizing: border-box`. А то может у тебя там вёрстка такая, что он тебе и не нужен.

Comment: Минусаторы, с чем конкретно не согласны?

Comment: Действительно... От меня лично +

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/266874)

Comment: @Темкатоже, почему?

Comment: Указанный ответ не является ответом, т.к. не раскрывает предназначение элемента `box-sizing`.

Comment: @Темкатоже, второе предложение раскрывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, впервые вижу подобное=)
Не согласен с "минусаторами"

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я вот тоже не готов это за ответ счесть) Думаю, тут не хватает пары слов о том что таки атрибут делает и как его использовать для случая `Когда элементы начнут вылазить на величину отступов`. Ну и можно привести пару строк кода когда он не нужен)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне кажется, вопрос ориентирован именно на полезность атрибута в коде, а не выражает непонимание того, на что он влияет. Впрочем, дополнил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне просто кажется, что можно было бы классный ответ соорудить, если б больше деталей было б и подробностей и особенностей применения, пользы и вреда от этого атрибута в реальной жизни)